# R Replace NaN in a Column data frame with the rowMean 3 next column in particular row

Tags: r, replace, nan

Note: in my real dataset, it cannot happen that there are less than two valid values in a row.

I want to replace NaN with the rowMeans of the particular row 
I tried to go with apply:

```
apply(dat,1, FUN= function(x) ifelse(is.na(x[1]),rowMeans(dat[,1:3], na.rm=TRUE), x[1]))
```

But with this on my data I always obtain the same vlaue if there is a NaN. The problems seems to be that in apply(,1,) I cannot write rowMeans(dat[1:3]) to obtain the particular value (I guess).

Comment: Can you give a reproductible example?

Comment: you're using `apply` with margin 1 so, as you already know, you're applying your function to each row, so `x` corresponds to a row. Hence, what you are looking for is probably something like: `apply(dat,1, FUN= function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE); x})`

Comment: it's perfect, thanks. I tried that also but apparently I had as x being set the complete dataset, so I got wrong values - silly, thx

Comment: @CathG you should post that as an answer and I'll ad  `mindreading` tag to the question so you'll gain some score on that tag